# Почему css стили не применяются?

Tags: html, css

HTML КОД

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Киномонстр - это портал о кино">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="keyword" content="фильмы, фильмы онлайн, hd">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="logo_text">
                    <h1><a href="/">КиноМонстр</a></h1>
                    <h2>Кино - наша страсть!</h2>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    </div>




</body>
</html>




CSS КОД


    .header {
      background-color: darkslateblue;
      height: 177px;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      min-width: 900px;
      }

    .main, .logo, .menubar, .site_content, .footer {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    .logo {
      width: 880px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

Уже не раз проверял расположение сss файла, не понимаю почему стили не подключаются

Comment: выложите полный путь до css и до html

Comment: D:/Kinomonstr/assets/css/style.css

Comment: ок, а путь к html?

Comment: В этот раз, указав расположение с самого начала, оно не считало папку Kinomonster, даже скопировал название с папки, все равно

Comment: То есть и в css я тоже должен указать путь, но только к html?

Comment: D:/Kinomonstr/assets/index.html

Comment: index.html тоже в assets лежит, значит в относительном пути assets должно отсутствовать: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, вы спасли мои нервы, которые и так были на пределе...

Answer (score 1):

A где у тебя html находится?
мне кажется что нужно

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```